# How is the word "Cactaceae" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, latin

I was wondering how the word Cactaceae, which is the botanical taxon for the Cactus family, is pronounced. I searched for "Cactaceae pronunciation" and [found](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=cactaceae) the following pronunciations:

cac-'tee-see-ee

cac-'tee-see-eye

It seemed a bit strange that the second *a* is pronounced as s**ee** rather than m**a**te so I searched on an [found](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cactaceae) the Merriam-Webster pronunciation, which reads:

\kakˈtāsēˌē\

If I'm not mistaken, this is to be parsed as

cac-'teh-see-ee

So, which one's the correct pronunciation? I don't suppose a lot of people have ever uttered this word out loud, but I have an upcoming presentation in English and will be using this word a lot.

Comment: http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=cactaceae&submit=Submit

Comment: @JoeDark: I have linked that page in my question. The way the man pronounces the word differs from Merriam-Webster's prescription. Hence the question.

Comment: @ Armen Ծիրունյան Just pick whichever version you prefer. I'm quite sure that everyone will think that your pronounciation is correct.

Comment: @JoeDark Your comments are uniformly anti-useful here: they do nothing to provide notational direction or realistic advice. I advise you to delete them.

Comment: The pronunciation in Joe's link by Howjsay is correct and traditional, especially /kækˈteɪsii/. I would stick with that. The ʃ is probably excusable. I don't understand why some people would pronouce *-ae* as /eɪ/: what precedent is there?

Comment: highly related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40671/pronunciation-of-words-ending-with-ae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being confused because of the misleadingly nonstandard pronunciation symbols being inexcusably thrust upon you by Merriam-Webster. It it in your best interest to ignore utterly any source whose pronunciation fails to use standard IPA.

Turning to a dictionary that **does** employ standard notation, the related word *cactaceous*, meaning per the OED:

> Belonging to the old genus Cactus; or to the natural order *Cactaceæ*.

is normally pronounced /kækˈteɪʃəs/ according to that same source.

That tells you how *Cactaceae* starts out, but leaves you a bit in the dark about how it finishes up.  Most of the remaining mystery lies in how the *‑aceae* suffix can be pronounced several ways, depending on one’s formative education and personal predilection.

So for example, although I myself — and I am hardly alone in this — pronounce the word *Cactaceae* as /kækˈteɪʃiɑɪ/, other people are more apt to say /kækˈteɪʃieɪ/ or /kækˈteɪʃeɪ/ there instead.

I have never heard /kækˈteɪʃi/ but can imagine it existing. Probably very few still pronounce it as if it were Classical Latin, so /kɑkˈtɑkiɑɪ/ or even with some small effort to preserve the diphthong, /kɑkˈtɑkiɑe/.

Mostly what is happening is that the /si/ becomes (as it so often does) /ʃi/ there; think of *spacious* and many other such words.

I recommend to you [the Wikipedia article on the ‘traditional’ English pronunciation of Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin).  This is still true in general, but studious specialists of a younger generation sometimes do more in the way of maintaining the Latin diphthongs than our elders were wont to do.

---

### Edit

As John Lawler astutely notes in comments, it may be important to preserve an unpalatalized /s/ instead of using /ʃ/ for the *‑aceae* suffix in some contexts, because that suffix is a clear marker to botanists that one is referring to a plant taxon at the Family level.

That would make it end in /esie/ phonemically — or, with explicit phonetic diphthongs and glides as always occurs in English, in [eɪsijeɪ]. It really depends on  how fancy you are getting with your notation, because those are the same thing.

The Anglophone botanists I know indeed use a simple /e/ (phonetic [eɪ]) for *ae*. I may hear the [ɑɪ] variant mainly from people who have spent more time with school-Latin than with actual English-speaking botanists. :)

Comment: When I used to hang around with botanists (I was on a couple PhD committees), they pronounced botanic Latin using standard English Latin pronunciation; i.e, /kæk'tesiye/ for _Cactaceae_. The suffixes are important because they can mark the taxonomic level (_-aceae_ indicates that it's a Family, for instance, not an Order or a Genus). A cactus specialist might well palatalize it to /kæk'teʃiye/, or if the taxon is not at issue, might just use an old label like /kæk'teʃəs/. But for most people who aren't biologists and don't play them on TV, /kæk'tesiye/ is the way to go.

Comment: @JohnLawler That sounds about right. The palatalization feels a bit lazy. I’m not sure that your `ʃiye` is different in realization from my `ʃieɪ`: you mark one glide and I mark another, but it seems to me that both happen at the phonetic level simply because of how those phonemes wind up getting said in real English.

Comment: Oh, by the way, if /kæk'tesiye/ looks weird to you, don't worry; it's just the American English phonemic alphabet, from Kenyon and Knott's _Pronouncing Dictionary of American English_. [More details here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf). @tchrist: yes, I think they're the same. Phonemics overgeneralizes.

Comment: @JohnLawler Oh, I’m used to your notation by now, although that’s probably an important addendum for folks expecting /j/ there per IPA.